# What could キョン untwist to?

Tags: word-requests, names

In the anime [Haruhi Suzumiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haruhi_Suzumiya) there is a main character called Kyon [キョン].

The wiki page for [Kyon](http://haruhi.wikia.com/wiki/Kyon) mentions:

> His nickname, Kyon, was created for him by his aunt and then spread by his little sister. **This is an "unwelcome twist" on his real name.**

Originally I thought it would be Kyou [杏], with the u replaced with a N to make it sound like a female nickname. Although the [answer here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30497) describes that'd be ん and not ン.

Leaving me curious as to what キョン could unravel to as a normal boys name.

Comment: See this: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43523/what-meaning-does-the-nickname-kyon-has

Comment: @Sweeper That answer is beside the mark.

Answer (score 1):

I read 涼宮ハルヒの憂鬱.

"ハルヒ" isn't a popular name for a Japanese woman, and "キョン" isn't a popular nickname, either. They are probably the author's own creation, so if you really want to get the correct answer, you should ask him.

Generally speaking, however, I can think of キョン as the nickname for:

> 恭一郎・京一郎・響一郎（kyou ichi rou) (man)
>
> 恭子・今日子・京子・**杏子**・響子 (kyou ko) (woman)
>
> 京太郎・姜太郎・京太朗 (kyou ta rou) (man)
>
> 恭介・恭輔・享佑・**杏輔** (kyou suke) (man)

Any woman and man's real names that start with "kyou" can be called キョン as their nickname.

For example, 響一郎 is rather a long and "heavy" name. But キョン is a very "light" name. The man doesn't like the nickname, so he said, "This is an 'unwelcome twist' on my real name," I believe.

As for the difference between ん and ン, I don't agree with you.

”Kyon" can be written as either ”きょん” or "キョン."

きょン or キョん looks very weird to my eyes.

> Although the answer here describes that be ん and not ン.

I don't think so.

One more thing to note:
小泉今日子 is a singer and actress in Japan, and her nickname is キョンキョン, not キョン.

Why キョンキョン, not キョン?

I think キョン is too "light." And it might resemble "チョン" which is a very dirty word in Japanese history.